# Improve azure pipeline performance by reducing checkout time

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

We have been using azure devops for a while now, and we have a very large suite in a repository, with an extensive yaml pipeline. It has all kinds of parallel jobs, and we have multiple hosted agents available to run the jobs in parallel. In order to speed up builds, I'm doing all kinds of optimizations (like caching nuget packages). However, because of the size of our repository, the pipeline jobs run about 2 and a half minutes before even starting any task, because it is running the checkout task to get the source to the hosted agent.

We probably added some large unnecessary files to the repository at the beginning of our project, and this probably caused the repository to bloat a bit. I've found some documentation on how to remove large files from the repository, but the document is quite vague about it. Is this a proper way to try to improve the checkout time? If so, is there anyone who can give me a detailed description on how to remove unwanted files from a git repository and pushing this to azure devops?

If there are any other things I can do to improve checkout speeds (apart from using private agents), I'm open to ideas

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The checkout behaviour can be customized by the `checkout` keyword. In particular it is possible to specify the `fetchDepth` (defaults to no limit) to do a shallow fetch, which could improve performance.

From the Azure devops docs on [Shallow Fetch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/pipeline-options-for-git?view=azure-devops#shallow-fetch):

> If your repository is large, this option might make your build
>   pipeline more efficient. Your repository might be large if it has been
>   in use for a long time and has sizeable history. It also might be
>   large if you added and later deleted large files.

Yaml pipeline example:

```
steps:
- checkout: self
  clean: true
  fetchDepth: 1 # Fetch only one commit
  path: PutMyCodeHere
```

Azure devops documentation for [how to specify fetchDepth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cparameter-schema&viewFallbackFrom=vsts#checkout) in yaml pipelines

Comment: That sounds really promising. I'll give it a go to see what the effect is

Comment: Are there any downsides to only getting 1 commit from git? For creating a build that is.

Comment: No, as long as you are only interacting with the current commit, which is generally the case in a build, there is no downside. What you cannot do is for example to show the git history, or to checkout or diff against other commits or branches. (comparing with the previous commit can easily be solved by specifying `fetchDepth: 2`, but to checkout or diff with a n arbitrary commit or branch you have to clone the whole repo, but those are not actions typically done in a build.

Comment: @danielorn Do you know if tools like GitVersion will be able to determine the correct version number? F.e. when building the development branch, it probably needs to read tags from the master/main branch?

Comment: drawback: if using Sonarcloud (or SonarQube) SAST, with fetchDepth: 1, the blame feature won't work.

Comment: @Eccentropy, Yes, any operation that requires the past history and not just the selected commit will be affected by specifying the `fetchDepth`

Answer (score 12):

Adding to the accepted answer, you may find `fetchTags` to help a lot if your repo has a lot of tags and you don't need them in your pipeline.

While our checkout step took 6 minutes with just `fetchDepth: 1`, when we added `fetchTags: false`, the clone step was reduced to 30 seconds. Our checkout step looks like this now.

```
  - checkout: self
    fetchDepth: 1
    fetchTags: false
```

Note: Newer repositories default to `fetchTags: false`. ([Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/steps-checkout?view=azure-pipelines#default-behavior))